# Upgrade Gitlab from source 7.4 to Docker 10.4

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I've been looking around for people trying to do such madness but can't find anything.

What I'm trying to do is upgrade from an old, unmaintained version of Gitlab 7.4.2 that was running on a server to a Docker version on 10.4.

I did my backup correctly with 7.4 but obviously as I'm trying to unpack it, I get the following :

```
Your current GitLab version (10.4.2) differs from the GitLab version in the backup!
Please switch to the following version and try again:
version: 7.4.2
```

I'm not sure of the procedure I should do next but have a few ideas I'd like to run by you here to see which is the easiest/most doable.

- Upgrade my bare-metal server gradually from 7.4 to 8.x, then to 9.x to have the minimum Docker version present on Docker Hub. Then do a backup and repeat the process on Docker.
- Force (how?) the Docker version to take this backup anyway
- An other solution maybe ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Madness indeed....

The brute force take of upgrading here is probably the way to go, as this is by far the safest one.

The only alternative I can offer is to migrate your source instance to the omni-bus installation of the same version an then let the package manager deal with the mess and update to the latest version.

But you should prepared for problems. [Non omni-bus to omni-bus installations are not tested](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/README.html#upgrading-from-a-non-omnibus-installation-to-an-omnibus-installation). If you want to try it anyway, [here is the upgrade guide for the omni-bus versions](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/README.html#updating-gitlab-via-omnibus-gitlab).

If you have then the newest version you can simply export and import it into the docker instance as the docker image simply contains a omni-bus instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upgrade Gitlab directly and must upgrade it step by step to the next major release: 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10.
You can see more information in the link below:

[https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/maintenance.html#upgrade-recommendations][1]

and execute the following commands:

```
sudo docker stop gitLab

sudo docker rm gitLab
```

You can see more information in the link below:

[https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#upgrade-gitlab-to-newer-version][1]

and after executing  2 above commands you can change the GitLab version that existing in the content of the docker-compose.yml .

examlpe:

```
gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:11.11.0
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
```

to chenged:

```
gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:12.7.6
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
```

and execute the following command:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Repeat these stages and Step by step between the GitLab versions to get the desired version.